# RDKit: Atom Indices to *.mol file

Tags: python, shortest-path, chemistry, rdkit

Question: How to convert atom indices into mol file?

Goal: Convert shortest path between atoms into mol file.

I have an initial mol file and am analyzing it using RDKit. I am getting the shortest path between two atoms using their indices. Example is shown in the figure where the shortest path is highlighted.

Specific function from RDKit: **GetShortestPath**
The input are the two atom indices and the output is a tuple, I am able to convert these tuple values into specific cells of data frame. I am unable to convert the path indices into a mol file where the shortest path becomes the new molecule. I am unsure what methods can be used or what processes. There seems to be no function available to go from mol-atom indices into separate mol-file.

Output of **GetShortestPath** in tuple form where initial at is 39 and ending atom is 25.

```
(39, 18, 21, 43, 25)
```

[Big molecule with highlighted shortest path between 39 and 25](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4YRYo.png)

I had tried searching for functions to convert mol-atom indices into seperate mol files but I have not found such functions. At this time I am uncertain what direction to go.

The fragment or substructure functions of RDKIT don't allow input from atom indices, from what I can tell.
I would appreciate any assistance in this matter and if you suggest different direction, that would be welcomed as well.

I expected to find a function converting paths into mol files based on atom indices but did not find any.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Using the mol file and the atom indices from "GetShortestPath", I was able to generate SMILES notation.
Though not shown, I can convert the SMILES notation to mol and then obtain *.mol file.

Example:

```
mol = Chem.MolFromMolFile('PrettyDimer.mol')
l = 39 # Initial Atom
m = 25 # End Atom
shortest_path = Chem.rdmolops.GetShortestPath((mol), (l), (m))

print(shortest_path) #Atom indices of path
print(Chem.MolFragmentToSmiles(mol, shortest_path))
```

OUTPUT:

```
(39, 18, 21, 43, 25)
COCco
```